# Azure Kusto query for selecting multiple function Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-log-analytics

I have an one azure function and it calls multiple Function apps. This is my query to select data from function.

> ```
> FunctionAppLogs | where FunctionName == "TestFunction" | project Category, Level, Message
> ```

This is loading correct. This Function uses many function apps. Now I need to select my App name here.  Is there a way to write a query to select function App name. Anyone have an idea to do this. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  the Resource id column , you can pull the logs a function app which were involved under a specific function invocations.

```
   FunctionAppLogs
| where FunctionName == "<functionName>" 
| where _ResourceId contains "<functionappName>" or ResoucreId contains "<functionName>
| project  Category, Level, Message,_ResourceId
```